# Enterprise Manager clone for SQL Server 2005 or later

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

Is there any project attempting to reproduce the functionality of [Enterprise Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_Manager) for SQL Server 2005 and newer?

I know [Aqua Data Studio](http://www.aquafold.com) is sort-of-close.

Are there any projects that understand some of [the virtues of the previous software and are trying to preserve it](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: Oh drat, i meant this for serverfault. Meh, maybe it's super user-y.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an open source project, or would you consider something like Toad or RapidSQL?

- http://www.quest.com/toad/
- http://www.embarcadero.com/products/rapid-sql
- http://www.embarcadero.com/products/db-powerstudio-xe

Also, this question might fit better on the dba.stackexchange.com site.

Edit: Additional links with DB management tools:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_database_tools
- http://www.sqlwebpedia.com/content/free-sql-server-tools

Comment: Also found the following related question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170/sql-server-management-studio-alternatives

Comment: i'm not opposed to closed source, but i'm certainly not interested in spending any money

Comment: I've pretty much stayed with Management Studio myself, adding another link to a list of tools that might be useful for you.